# Combine two scripts into one

Tags: jquery

I have those two scripts; first works on page load and second after ajax call, how to combine them into one?

```
<script>
$('.togglestuff').click(function() {
    $('.views-table').toggle('slow');
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('.togglestuff').click(function() {
        $('.views-table').toggle('slow');
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.togglestuff', function() {
    $('.views-table').toggle('slow');
});
```

This is delegating an event handler from `document` for all **current** and **future** `.togglestuff` elements

**Update**

If you are using an older jQuery version which does not support `on()`, a workaround would be

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   if(e.target.className == 'togglestuff'){
       $('.views-table').toggle('slow');
   }
});
```

Comment: It's not working with jquery 1.2.6 because it's been added in 1.7 and I'm using drupal 6 which has old version.

Comment: I'm having problem with this, it's a dropdown menu but it keeps hiding immediatelly after clicking it don't know why,  with  on. function this doesn't happen but then after the element is refreshed via ajax it's not working anymore..